# Waves. What does it mean by waves occupying space?

Tags: waves

I am currently learning high school physics and came across the following statement " **waves can occupy the same space at the same time**". I don't understand what this means and I would greatly appreciate if someone can explain this for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe what you are referring to is some aspect of the superposition principle. Basically, what it means is that two waves can exist in the same location, with their respective values adding linearly. Think of two water waves travelling in opposite directions. They don't bounce off each other, but rather pass through each other, with their respective effects adding up (they "stack"). To do that, they must be able to exist in the same location. The same is not true for classical particles, which would bounce off each other.

Comment: @KarimAED Make you comment an answer!

Comment: have you seen small ripples on a big hump of wave in the ocean?

Comment: In his 2021 pop-sci book titled "Fear of a Black Universe", physicist Stephon Alexander has considerable entry-level views about waves and wave functions, found by those terms in its index:  It may be available via inter-library loan, if not in the OP's local library.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are referring to is some aspect of the superposition principle. Basically, what it means is that two waves can exist in the same location, with their respective values adding linearly. If you are interested in learning more about this, [this wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) is a great starting point.

Think of two water waves travelling in opposite directions. They don't bounce off each other, but rather pass through each other, with their respective effects adding up (they "stack"). To do that, they must be able to exist in the same location. The same is not true for classical particles, which would bounce off each other.

Answer (score 1):

It just means to be present in that space.

The whole point of that statement is that they don't occupy the space in the sense of preventing other waves from being there at the same time.